# How to show multilevel dropdown menu in opencart category module?

Tags: php, opencart

I want to Show Multilevel Dropdown menu in opencart 2.0 category module

```
Menu>submenu>submenu1>submenulevel2>level3>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain if you want this in the Admin area or the customer front end?

In which case in **category.tpl** just modify or write something like this:

```
<?php if ($categories) { ?>
               <?php if (count($categories) <= 5) { ?>
                 <div class="col-sm-3 nosidepadding">
                   <ul>
                     <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
                     <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
                     <?php } ?>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
               <?php } else { ?>
               <?php foreach (array_chunk($categories, ceil(count($categories) / 4)) as $categories) { ?>
                 <div class="col-sm-3 nosidepadding">
                   <ul>
                     <?php foreach ($categories as $category) { ?>
                     <li><a href="<?php echo $category['href']; ?>"><?php echo $category['name']; ?></a></li>
                     <?php } ?>
                   </ul>
                 </div>
               <?php } ?>
               <?php } ?>
               <?php } ?>
```